# Why can't i display my movies by React JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, use-state

I'm making a movies app  but my codes do not work. The mistake announced is "
./src/App.js:  'MovieList' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef"
I don't know what is wrong? Can anybody help me? Thank you so much!

This is my App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';


function App() {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([{
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope",
            "Year": "1977",
            "imdbID": "tt0076759",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzVlY2MwMjktM2E4OS00Y2Y3LWE3ZjctYzhkZGM3YzA1ZWM2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back",
            "Year": "1980",
            "imdbID": "tt0080684",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYmU1NDRjNDgtMzhiMi00NjZmLTg5NGItZDNiZjU5NTU4OTE0XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi",
            "Year": "1983",
            "imdbID": "tt0086190",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOWZlMjFiYzgtMTUzNC00Y2IzLTk1NTMtZmNhMTczNTk0ODk1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens",
            "Year": "2015",
            "imdbID": "tt2488496",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTAzODEzNDAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU1MTgzNzE@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace",
            "Year": "1999",
            "imdbID": "tt0120915",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYTRhNjcwNWQtMGJmMi00NmQyLWE2YzItODVmMTdjNWI0ZDA2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith",
            "Year": "2005",
            "imdbID": "tt0121766",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNTc4MTc3NTQ5OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTg0NjI4NA@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones",
            "Year": "2002",
            "imdbID": "tt0121765",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDAzM2M0Y2UtZjRmZi00MzVlLTg4MjEtOTE3NzU5ZDVlMTU5XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDUyOTg3Njg@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode VIII - The Last Jedi",
            "Year": "2017",
            "imdbID": "tt2527336",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjQ1MzcxNjg4N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzgwMjY4MzI@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode IX - The Rise of Skywalker",
            "Year": "2019",
            "imdbID": "tt2527338",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDljNTQ5ODItZmQwMy00M2ExLTljOTQtZTVjNGE2NTg0NGIxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODkzNTgxMDg@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Solo: A Star Wars Story",
            "Year": "2018",
            "imdbID": "tt3778644",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTM2NTI3NTc3Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzM1OTQyNTM@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
    ])
    return <div >
        <
        MovieList movies = { movies }
    />


    <
    /div>
}

export default App;
```

This is my MovieList.js:

```
import React from 'react'

const MovieList = (props) => {
    return ( < > {
            props.movies.map((movie, index) => < div >
                <
                img src = { movie.Poster }
                alt = "movie" > < /img> < /
                div >
            )
        } <
        />
    )
}


export default MovieList;
```

My "MoviesList" file is inside my "components" folder and my "components" and my "App" folder are inside my "src" folder

Comment: You don't import `MovieList` in App

Comment: FYI, `<img />` tags are self-closing. There is no `</img>` end tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the `MovieList` file in App.js

```
import MovieList from 'the path of the file'
```